# How to Reset Window Layout in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac

Is it possible to reset window layout in Visual Studio for Mac? I am able to do this for Visual Studios on Windows, but not on Mac version.

Comment: I actually lost my Application Output window/pad and can't get it back...

Answer (score 25):

After piecing together various posts I found only a non-UI way to reset the layout. Starting with this doc: http://www.monodevelop.com/developers/articles/user-profiles/ but instead of using the path "MonoDevelop" use "VisualStudio". So in the case of a Mac the folder to visit is at "~/Library/Preferences/VisualStudio".

Once there I found the "7.0" subfolder had a file named "EditingLayout.xml"... With VS for Mac not running, I deleted that file and started it again. This restored all pads to their default state from what I can tell. In my case the "Application Output" window was still not available as a Pad until I actually did a Debug on a project, and then it was visible again in the View | Pads list (and no longer lost in the UI somewhere).

Comment: This should absolutely be the accepted answer as of today's date.  I would have never figured this out on my own.

Comment: Still works. File only shows up when you completely quit VS.

Comment: Deleting the whole `7.0` directory fixed my problem of the top menu bar (with build / run buttons, etc…) not appearing anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You can press the view tab to change the different layouts or create one of your own.

[image: View Tab]

Additional informations can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/customizing-the-ide?view=vsmac-2019

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem also, Visual Studio for Mac can't reset Window Layout in UI. But you can easily customize the Window Layout. Just select "View->Pads/Debug Pads" to decide what window you want to show on the dashboard.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3wPl.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Just to have a more up-to-date answer: when you quit Visual Studio Mac 2019, any changes made to the active layout will be reset to how the layout was saved.

From the Visual Studio Website:"There is always one active layout and any change you make in a layout, such as adding or repositioning a pad, will only change the active layout. Once you close Visual Studio for Mac, the changes you have made will not be saved." [Visual Studio Website - Customising The IDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/customizing-the-ide?view=vsmac-2019)

I've tested it out for Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac Version 8.7.8 (build 4), and now it really does just reset when you quit the app, unless you have specifically saved any changes as a new layout.